# java split function. Store in an array from custom index?

Tags: java, groovy

I want to split a string and store in an array from custom index and NOT from "0" index by default.

Eg:

```
String splitThis = "cat,dog";
String [] array = splitThis.split(",");
System.out.println array[0] + array[1]
```

Above code prints "catdog" but I want "cat" to be store in index "1" and "dog" in index "2"

PS: I am very new to Programming and this is my very first question. Please correct me in syntax/logic/whatever :)

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: split returns an array of size 2, so there is no index 2 to move it to. You need another array, and a method to put them in the desired index

Comment: Downvote for this absolutely absurd  goal.

Answer (score -1):

You may just add an empty entry at index 0. Something like this

```
String splitThis = "cat,dog";
String spit2 = ","+splitThis;
String [] array = split2.split(",");
System.out.println (array[1]);
System.out.println (array[2]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should probably create an entirely new class to handle that.

Comment: or entirely new language